# Limit at infinity involving $e$

Tags: limits

I am to find the limit of $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{5x^3+x^2+8}\right)^ {\dfrac{x^3+8}{x}}$$

I could not find the proper substitution here. I would be happy if someone could shed some light. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac 1{5x^2})^{x^2}$$ for large x, if that technique is correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{5x^3+x^2+8}\right)^{\frac{x^3+8}{x}}
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{5x^2+x+8/x}\right)^{x^2+8/x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{5x^2+x+8/x}\right)^{(5x^2+x+8/x)\frac{x^2+8/x}{5x^2+x+8/x}}\\
&=\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{5x^2+x+8/x}\right)^{(5x^2+x+8/x)}\right)^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2+8/x}{5x^2+x+8/x}}\\[6pt]
&=e^{1/5}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{5x^3+x^2+8}\right)^ {x^2+8/x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{5x^2+x+8/x}\right)^ {x^2+8/x}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{5x^2+x+8/x}\right)^{5x^2+x+8/x} \right)^{\frac{x^2+8/x}{5x^2+x+8/x}}=e^{1/5}$$
because
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{5x^2+x+8/x}\right)^{5x^2+x+8/x}=e$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{x^2+8/x}{5x^2+x+8/x}}=\frac{1}{5}$$